# div tag control placement

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a div tag like in the following.

```
<div>
    <asp:LinkButton  runat="server" Text="aaaa"  />
    <asp:LinkButton  runat="server" Text="bbbb" />
</div>
```

These two link buttons are placed one after the other, in the same line.

But I want them to be in two lines.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add a `<br>` in between?

Comment: It worked ! Thank You !

Comment: @chrillelundmark `</br>`? Did you just invent a new tag?

Comment: @UweKeim Apparently :S I intended to write <br />, thanks for noticing me.

Answer (score 1):

Another elegant way to achieve this-

```
<div>
    <asp:LinkButton  runat="server" Text="aaaa"  />
</div>
<div>
    <asp:LinkButton  runat="server" Text="bbbb" />
</div>
```

The reason for this approach:

`<br>` is for content and...

`<div>` combined with CSS is for styling